# List of Actionscript 3 events

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

Is there a way to get a list of events available in Actionscript 3? Like `MouseEvent.CLICK` and `Event.ENTER_FRAME` but the full list to look at. I tried searching the manual on Adobe's site, but just couldn't find it. I'm using the flex plugin inside Eclipse if that makes any difference.

Comment: Note that you can always add new event constants, so you can only really get an exhaustive list of the events available in the standard libraries, not the in the language itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html

On each of the many subclass links, you'll find the constants you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Matt!

I would like to add to this post, since it helped me find what I needed.

For those that are looking for alternates like Dan is, here is a small explanation of what you're (I think) looking for. They're called Classes of the Flash.Events package.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/package-detail.html

There you will find different classes and sub classes to use when working with functions, events, listeners and more. Just go to Event and MouseEvent, and I'm sure you'll find the familiar ENTER_FRAME and Click events that you're already familiar with. Enjoy!